# String in ArrayList Not Outputting

Tags: java, string, list, algorithm, system.out

I have the following method which takes user input and applies an algorithm to it. However when I try to print the String process_name, stored in the **fcfs** ArrayList it comes out empty. But the burst_time and arrival_time fields in the same **fcfs** ArrayList get output to the console exactly as the user inputted the data. Not really sure what could be wrong.

```
public static void algorithm() {


        ArrayList<Process> fcfs = new ArrayList<>();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Process name,CPU Burst Time,Arrival time\n ");

        while (!scan.next().equalsIgnoreCase("finish")) {

            Process p = new Process();

            String pn = "";
            String bt = "";
            String at = "";
            pn = input.nextLine();
            bt = input.nextLine();
            at = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Process name, CPU Burst Time, Arrival time\n ");

            p.process_name = pn;
            p.burstTime = Float.parseFloat(bt);
            p.arrivalTime = Float.parseFloat(at);
            fcfs.add(p);

        }

        

        {

            Collections.sort(fcfs, new comp());
        }

    

        
        result(fcfs, fcfs.size(),false)

    }
```

This is the Process class:

```
class Process {
    String process_name;
    float burstTime;
    float arrivalTime;
    float compTime = 0;
    boolean status = false;

}
```

Comment: I don't see the declaration of the variable `input`. What is it? Should it be the Scanner variable?

Comment: @RiccardoChimisso yes that's right

Comment: Do you have access to the `Process` class? Seeing the code in that class could be helpful.

Comment: @EvanBailey it just has variables inside, no methods

Answer (score 2):

scan.next() function gets the next input string. That is why you get an empty line for process name because the name is already taken by the next function in the while condition. Either use hasNext() to check if there is a next line or get and put input to a string variable and compare it with the word 'finish'.

You can see the explanation in the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()

Quoting from the documentation: "next : Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of using `next()` instead of `nextLine()`. Check [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) to learn more about it.

Replace

```
while (!scan.next().equalsIgnoreCase("finish"))
```

with

```
while (!scan.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("finish"))
```

Also, it's better to use `do...while` which guarantees to execute its body at least once i.e.

```
do {

    Process p = new Process();

    String pn = "";
    String bt = "";
    String at = "";
    pn = input.nextLine();
    bt = input.nextLine();
    at = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Process name, CPU Burst Time, Arrival time\n ");

    p.process_name = pn;
    p.burstTime = Float.parseFloat(bt);
    p.arrivalTime = Float.parseFloat(at);
    fcfs.add(p);

} while (!scan.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("finish"));
```